# MaskEditExtender Ajax toolkit- not able to copy paste IE 11

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender

I have two date textboxes in my ASP.Net application and these textboxes are using MaskEditExtender so that only date can be entered in them. These textboxes are actually from and to textboxes to enter a date range. 
The issue is that in IE 11 the user is not able to copy-paste date from one text box to other using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V. 
The user is able to paste the date by right clicking and selecting copy paste but in this also the date does not get properly formatted in the second textbox. In IE8 and lower browsers it worked fine.
Sample code used:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
            Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" ClipboardEnabled="true"/>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server"  TargetControlID="TextBox2"
             Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" ClipboardEnabled="true"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a bug that was fixed recently, but this fix is not published at the moment.

You can see changes [here](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/c113d2f67785a20d3ccb80af5707c6f4a7bef78b) or wait for new ACT release.